# Count how many times a number has appeared in a cell

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a table that counts how many times a number has appeared in a cell. For example, if a randomly generated number between 1 and 10 showed up as seven, then the marked cell will add 1 to the current number. If it showed 3, it would add 1 to the appropriate cell.

[image: It would look like this]

I would like to know a formula for how to do this. Can anyone help?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with formula:

First you must allow iterative calculations.  Go to File --> Options --> Formulas and click the box by Enable iterative calculations. And the Max iterations to 1

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then the formula would be:

```
=IF($D$2<>"",0,IF($D$6=A2,B2+1,B2))
```

I put the `IF($D$2<>"",0...` part so you can reset the counts to 0 by putting anything in D2.  It will reset all the counts to `0`

In D6 put your RANDBETWEEN formula.

Then just hit F9 to recalculate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formulas will only calculate based on what is currently displayed. You will need a macro to modify the spreadsheet each time it is refreshed. If you are okay with having a column of random numbers, you can use `COUNTIF` to calculate the scores.

Comment: This is not really a site where you post your requirements and someone writes the code for you, but a place for specific questions about problems with existing code.  If you don't already know some VBA, this is not a good place to get a start.

Comment: Sure sorry mate. Bit clueless when it comes to excel.